# django backend and angular frontend send request to backend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

hello I have finished learn `angular 7` **basics now** have combined django from the back and angular for the from I am in the start of this project

now I am using `rest_framework` for django and I want angular to send a `GET` request to the backend as we know django uses `127.0.0.1:8000` and angular `127.0.0.1:4200` and when I do this function

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  users: Object;
  recvedData: boolean = false;
  hasError: boolean = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('/api/qutes').subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
      this.recvedData = true;
      this.hasError = true;
      console.log(error);
   })
 }
}
```

I am trying to get data from `/api/quets` from the backend server
 **but** it requesting the data from the frontend server (`127.0.0.1:4200/api/quets`) and this URL does not exists I know I can add a `service` with variable `domain = "127.0.0.1:8000"` and to `this.http.get(this.service.domain +"/api/quets")` 
**my question:**

> there is a better way to do that? so it send all of the request to the `backend` server automatically?

Comment: better way such as what ?

Comment: that can write `this.http.get("api/quotes")` and not `this.http.get("127.0.0.1:8000/api/quotes")`

Comment: unless `api` itself contains `127.0.0.1:8000/api/`, else , you cannot AFAIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you setup a proxy, you can just write the urls as `/api`, all calls of `http://localhost:4200/api` will be diverted to `http://localhost:3000/api`.

[From angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server):

> You can use the [proxying support](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) in the webpack dev server to divert certain URLs to a backend server, by passing a file to the `--proxy-config` build option. For example, to divert all calls for `http://localhost:4200/api` to a server running on `http://localhost:3000/api`, take the following steps.

The steps mentioned in docs are:

Create a file `proxy.conf.json` in the projects `src/` folder, next to `package.json`.

Add the following content to the new proxy file:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

In the CLI configuration file, `angular.json`, add the `proxyConfig` option to the serve target:

```
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

To run the dev server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

You can edit the proxy configuration file to add configuration options; some examples are given in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server). For a description of all options, see [webpack DevServer documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy).

Note that if you edit the proxy configuration file, you must relaunch the `ng serve` process to make your changes effective.